# C assembly implement bubble sort

Tags: c, assembly, x86, intel, bubble-sort

I have to write a bubblesort in C with assembly implement.
My C code looks like :

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int arraysort(int array[],int length);
int main () {
    int array[]= {7,4,3,6,2,1};
    int length = 6;
    printf("Unsorted array: %d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],array[4],array[5]);
    arraysort(array,length);
    printf("Sorted array: %d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],array[4],array[5]);

    return 0;
}
```

And my assembly code looks like:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.text
.global arraysort
arraysort: # int sortarray(int array[],int length)

    #function prologue
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    # function prologue end

    push ebx   # save ebx for cdecl convection
    # 1.argumentum [ebp + 4*2] this is the array
    # 2.argumentum [ebp + 4*3] this is the length

    mov ecx, [ebp + 12]   #array length (6)
    dec ecx               #array length (5)
    mov edx, 1            #variable j
    mov esi, [ebp + 8] #array address
loop1:
      cmp ecx, 0  # (int i =length; i> length;i--)
      jg end
    loop2:
    mov eax, [esi + 4*ecx] #array[0]
    mov ebx, [esi + 4*edx] #array[1]
    cmp eax, ebx #if eax > ebx jump to csere
    jg swap
    dec ecx  #i--
    inc edx#j++
    jz end
    jmp loop2

swap:
    mov [esi + 4*edx], eax #change the two elements
    mov [esi + 4*ecx], ebx
    jmp loop2

end: 
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

I dont know what is the problem and I struggling whit this.
If I change in the first loop jg to jl i get infinity loop :/
Sorry for my english and my assembly coding skill but I'm learning this language still.
Please help me! Thank you

Comment: What is the actual behaviour of the code (aka output)?

Comment: And I cannot see how you managed to use loop1. There is no `jmp loop1` or that sort of code

Comment: The actual output is: The program print the unsorted array,the function dont do anything and print the sorted array.I forgot to write jmp loop1 maybe this is the problem and this is why I get infinity loop with jl ?

Comment: trace single step in debugger.  See what happens in code, fix bugs?

Comment: quite curious about the logic in the assembly code. `ecx` is the first loop variable, and `edx` is the second; however, why are one comparing `[esi+4*ecx]` with `[esi+4*edx]`? Shouldn't one have another register, say `aex`, and let `aex` be `edx-1` using code like `dec edx; mov aex edx; inc edx` and then compare `[esi+4*edx]` with `[esi+4*aex]`?

Comment: For a hint, I'd write it in C and use godbolt to output to assembler.  Cheating if you turn it in, but gives you an example that works.

Comment: It's really odd that you're "optimizing" the notoriously absurdly slow bubble sort in assembly. If you're going to take the time to write in assembly why not something at least as robust as Quick Sort?

Comment: @tadman: I'm pretty sure this is just homework for learning asm at all.  There are lots of minor inefficiencies in branch layout, choice of addressing modes, and other stuff, and no obvious sign of any optimization (although some stuff is right, like putting a conditional branch at the bottom of a loop).  Also this is walking indices in opposite directions starting from the begin/end of the array, not comparing adjacent elements, so it's not Bubble Sort and unlikely to actually sort at all.  If it was Bubble Sort, you'd probably want to reuse `a[i+1]` in a register as next iteration's `a[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the main problem:

```
    mov ecx, [ebp + 12]   #array length (6)
    dec ecx               #array length (5)
    mov edx, 1            #variable j
    mov esi, [ebp + 8] #array address
loop1:
      cmp ecx, 0  # (int i =length; i> length;i--)
      jg end
```

Focus on `ecx` there. You're basically saying `if(--length > 0) goto end;`, so you're skipping the entire meat of your function.

Now once you fix that, you'll start getting a segfault. Here's why:

```
    dec ecx  #i--
    inc edx#j++
    jz end
```

That's equivalent to `--i; if(!++j) goto end;`. As a result, your loop is going to run way more iterations than you want (until `j` overflows, but in practice it will segfault first). I'm guessing you meant to switch `dec ecx` and `inc edx`, so that the loop would end when `i` got to 0.

Anyway, with that fixed too, your code will return an updated array, but it will still be wrong. At this point, it's just because your bubble sort is wrong and not because of any assembly-related errors, so I'll stop here.